# create map using template

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I try to make a map with template; so here what I did so far.

my heade file ; in the cpp file I have just the signature of the ctor and dtor.

```
namespace VTBasics
{
 class __declspec(dllexport) INIReader
   {
     public :
        INIReader(const std::string & filename);
        ~INIReader();


     private :
     template<typename T>
     using INIData = typename std::map <std::string, std::map<T,std::string>>;
     ^^^^^^^^ 
    (error this line)


    template<typename T>
    INIData<T>_values;

 };
}
```

when compiling i got this error ;

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
```

Comment: A class may not have member data that are dependent on a template parameter. When you create an instance of `INIReader`, how will the compiler know to initialize the member variable `_values`?

Comment: @RSahu so I could'nt write something like INIData<int> MyMap ?

in that case how to do to be able to use same calss for map with int and another with string ?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd, you'd have to make the IniReader class itself a template, but it is not practical.

Comment: There are [*variable templates*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) in C++14+. But only [static data members can be templated](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/572077847daa6517).

Comment: @Constructor : Yes I agree I did a little thing like that and worked but as you said it's c++14 and I have at work we usee c++11.

Comment: @SergeyA : is there a little tuto that it may helps ?

Comment: What's the ultimate point of the exercise? Imagine that, somehow, you got this code to compile; how would you use your `INIReader` class?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : what I need is to use a single class that could handle map with strings keys or map with int keys. (oe others if I could)

Comment: Again - suppose you managed to implement that class as you envision it. Show how you are planning to use it, how you are going to exercise this unique ability of allowing keys of different types.

Comment: Possibly [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) are what you are searching for.